# Not able to navigate to fragment - kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to Navigate from Activity(home page) to Fragment(add medi page) using button. But when I replace with (addmedi) error show.

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {

    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addMedButton)
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.editMedButton)


        button.setOnClickListener {

            fun onClick(){
                val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontener, addMedi/* my fragment 1 page*/)
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                fragmentTransaction.commit()

            }
        }
    }
```

The image is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePKp0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addMedButton)
    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.editMedButton)

         fun onClick(){
            val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontener, addMedi()/* my fragment 1 page*/)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()

        }
    button.setOnClickListener {
       onClick()
   
    }
}
```

or

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addMedButton)
    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.editMedButton)


    button.setOnClickListener {

        fun onClick(){
            val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontener, addMedi()/* my fragment 1 page*/)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()

        }
        onClick()
    }
}
```

b/c declaring function inside method won't magically call it
plus as I saw from the image `addMei` is class and should be called like `addMedi()` instead of `addMedi`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an instance of your fragment. So you need to pass `AddMedi()`